# Stretch flexbox item vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make the list take up all the blue space, but I don't want to add another item.
I could just give the items the right amount of padding to make it fit perfectly, but I feel like that's not the right way. So I thought there must be a way to do this with flexbox.

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R4LoR93eBRtkhMCnlTVy?p=preview) and snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

#art1 {
  flex: 2;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

#art2 {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

#art1>img,
#art1>p {
  flex: 1;
}

article {}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #art1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.activiteiten {
  background: yellow;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.activiteiten>li {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article id="art1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x250" alt="">
  </article>
  <article id="art2">
    <ul class="activiteiten">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `ul` a *flexbox* too:

```
height: 100%;
margin: 0; // reset the margin
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; // list vertically
justify-content: space-around; // spread the li vertically
```

and add `flex: 1` to the `li`s

See demo below:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

main {
    display: flex;
}

#art1 {
    flex: 2;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
}

#art2 {
    background: blue;
    flex: 1;
}

#art1>img,
#art1>p{
    flex: 1;
}

article {}

article ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

article ul li {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #art1 {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.activiteiten {
    background: yellow;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.activiteiten>li{
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article id="art1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x250" alt="">
  </article>
  <article id="art2">
    <ul class="activiteiten">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: It does what I asked for, but now I ran into another problem. Because the `li`'s don't sit against each other you can see the `ul` background. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/e80iI), hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you so much! Btw, isn't `justify-content: space-around` unnecessary now?